# sql oracle truncate user

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to truncate the USER function in Oracle and still use the alias USER. This is because I dont have access to a row trigger before update that user the USER (oracle username and my oracle username exceeds the character limit)

```
SELECT SYSDATE, REPLACE(USER,'NINETEEN','NINET') as USER FROM DUAL;
```

This doesn't work. The key is that USER must be the alias. Works fine if I don't use this, but I "need" to keep USER so the trigger works.

Here is the trigger (I can't change it as I do not have the privileges).

```
create or replace trigger tr_upd
before update on tableA
  for each row
begin
  :new.dateofchange := sysdate;
  :new.userofchange:= user;
```

The problem is my Oracle user is too long. I need to shorten it (before I update) - but not permanently.

Comment: It's really unclear to me. Please post an example of your starting situation, showing what you need to get. For example, you write about a trigger, which trigger? And what do you mean with "truncate USER" ?

Comment: Sorry but your question is completely unclear. Please carefully describe step by step what you need to obtain. Show how looks code/data before change and what is a desired result.

Comment: `as "USER"` maybe?

Comment: @Aleksej  @ Kacper - just updated it - I need to shorten my oracle username before I update - this is the problem...

Comment: `:new.userofchange:= REPLACE(USER,'NINETEEN','NINET')` ?

Comment: OP stated in the question that he can't modify the trigger

Comment: I cannot modify the trigger - it needs to happen in the sql query

Comment: You only have three options (afaik): 1. either get the privs necessary or get someone else to update the trigger to use `substr(user, <num of chars available in userofchange>)`,  2. get the userofchange column size increased, or 3. create a user with a short enough name and use that instead.

Comment: `USER` is not a value you handle in your query, it's something Oracle "knows" and you can not edit, so I believe you have no way to make a trigger ( or whatever else) consider `USER` with a value different from the real `USER`

Comment: Personally, I'd talk to whoever it is that wrote that trigger / designed the table and report a bug, assuming that's not you from what you said (you have no privs to update the trigger yourself).

Comment: tableA.userofchange column should be increased imo (to at least varchar2(30)).

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is SUBSTR, which reduces a string value down to a specific number of characters ([more info on SUBSTR here](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-substr/)):

For example:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, SUBSTR(USER, 1, x) as "USER" FROM DUAL;
```

Replace "x" with the length of your userofchange column.

Also, I would suggest increasing the length of the userofchange column. If it's meant to store the username but it is too short, it's not doing it's job properly.